# Ionic with Phonegap camera Plugin

Tags: cordova, camera, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I am building a hybrid application with the ionic framework that utilizes the device's camera. I came across a custom camera overlay on github and was wondering if anyone knows how I would integrate this into my ionic application. Ionic has documented that it is possible to add in Cordova custom plugins.

Link to the plugin I wish to add:

https://github.com/performanceactive/phonegap-custom-camera-plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ionic is based on Cordova, you can add Cordova plugin in Cordova way. Open an command prompt and navigate to your root source folder, type:

```
root folder> cordova plugin add https://github.com/performanceactive/phonegap-custom-camera-plugin
```

Or in Ionic way:

```
root folder> ionic plugin add https://github.com/performanceactive/phonegap-custom-camera-plugin
```

For detail of the CLI, please check

- https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html
- http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/

Comment: I successfully added the plugin to my ionic framework, however do I still need to add 'ngCordova' to dependencies and import the js file into ionic or should I be able to use the plugin  after installing it through the ionic CLI?

Comment: 'ngCordova' is a set of AngularJS wrappers of common Cordova plugins. It's not a mandatory requirement. Also, In you case, 'ngCordova' will not help for that custom plugin. Go with those JS files come with the custom plugin are enough.

Comment: for some reason ionic is not pickup up that the plugin is present. I have added the plugin to my config in the following manner just as the directions suggests. like so,



  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
  <gap:plugin name="com.performanceactive.plugins.camera" />

Comment: If "gap:plugin" syntax work, maybe you are using PhoneGap Build.

Comment: i am trying to use this on an ionic framework which is build off cordova

Comment: so do  think that it wont work because its only on phonegap build